# box-shadow and IE9 compatibilty

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I try to use box-shadow with `css3`, but it's not working on IE, works fine on chrome and firefox.

- I know, on `IE9` I must used box-shadow without `moz` or `webkit` prefix
- I use an iFrame in my WebPage for login (Made for ERP login), And this iframe have a known bug, when you use `html5` you can  be redirected after login, That's why I must use `<html>` tag and not `<!DOCTYPE html>` (I've open a ticket for fix this bug)
- If I use `<!DOCTYPE html>` my box-shadow work, but my iframe freeze.
- If I use `<html>` My iFrame work fine but my box-shadow is not diplayed.
  So, actually I must choose between design or functionality, but I'm pretty sure stackoveflow know an issue for that.

If you know a solution or a hack, it can be cool

Here my code : (work with `<!DOCTYPE hml>` but want the same effect with `<html>`)

```
    #header-container{
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 5px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
       -moz-box-shadow:0 5px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
            box-shadow:0 5px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);

}
```

Comment: The `<!DDOCTYPE hml>` is invalid HTML statement. It should be `<!DOCTYPE html>` if you want HTML5 document definition.

Comment: My fault bodi0, wrong type with my keyboard. Just one D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS3 `box-shadow`  is a **[Candidate Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#box-shadow)**.

It is method of displaying an inner or outer shadow effect to elements and it can be **partially emulated** in older IE versions using the non-standard `shadow` filter. Partial support in Safari, iOS Safari and Android Browser refers to missing `inset` and blur radius value support.

`IE9` has **no problem** showing `box-shadow` **except** when shadowing a box **within** a table-cell (If the CSS of the table has its `border-collapse` property set to `collapse`, then the `box-shadow` is not applied. This is fixed in a future releases).

As mentioned earlier, IE6-8 requires **Visual Filters** to emulate `CSS3` box-shadows **without** JavaScript. In order to illustrate this, I will show several different types of box-shadows below and show both the `CSS3` syntax and the equivalent **Visual Filter** CSS recipe. Some of these recipes produce almost identical results, while others are rough equivalents.

Note that all these examples use a *variation of Paul Irish’s Conditional CSS Pattern* in order to create the IE-only rules. This involves replacing the `<body>` tag of the document with this HTML:

```
<!-- Extra white-space below is just to make it easier to read. :-) -->

   <!--[if lt IE 7 ]>   <body class="ie6">          <![endif]-->
   <!--[if IE 7 ]>      <body class="ie7">          <![endif]-->
   <!--[if IE 8 ]>      <body class="ie8">          <![endif]-->
   <!--[if IE 9 ]>      <body class="ie9">          <![endif]-->
   <!--[if (gt IE 9) ]> <body class="modern">       <![endif]-->
   <!--[!(IE)]><!-->    <body class="notIE modern"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

We can then apply CSS specific to a version of IE. For example:

```
body.ie7 #box {
   /* insert IE7 specific CSS here */
}
```

(Note: Paul Irish’s technique officially has the conditional comments around the html tag, not the body tag. You can use either for these techniques to work. I just prefer using the latter.)

All these **Visual Filter** recipes depend on the box “having layout”. If you have any difficulty with the **Visual Filters** activating, set `zoom: 1` or a `static` width inside the IE6-8 specific CSS to force the block to have layout.

**Type #1: Simple, Unblurred Shadows**

In order to simulate simple, un-blurred box-shadows in IE, we use **IE’s DropShadow Visual filter**:

```
#box {
  /* CSS for all browsers. */
  border: solid 1px #808080;
  background: #ffffcc;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;

  /* CSS3 Box-shadow code: */
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0px #ff0000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 0px #ff0000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 0px #ff0000;
}

/* IE6-8 Specific Code */
body.ie6 #box,
body.ie7 #box,
body.ie8 #box {
   zoom: 1;
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(OffX=5, OffY=5, Color=#ff0000);
}
```

There are **two exceptions** to this solution. The first deals with when the block has a `transparent` background, and the other has to do with negative `box-shadow` offsets.

**Type #1a: Blocks With Transparent Backgrounds**

Let’s say you use the above CSS, but omit the background property:

```
#box {
  /* CSS for all browsers.  Note there is no background-color, so box will be transparent */
  border: solid 1px #808080;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;

  /* CSS3 Box-shadow code: */
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0px #ff0000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 0px #ff0000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 0px #ff0000;
}

/* IE6-8 Specific Code */
body.ie6 #box,
body.ie7 #box,
body.ie8 #box {
   zoom: 1;
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(OffX=5, OffY=5, Color=#ff0000);
}
```

Doing this will results in some unexpected results in IE6-8. The results in IE7 are as hideous and unreadable as the average [YTMND](http://yourethemannowdog.ytmnd.com/) page! In order to fix this issue in elderly IE, one must **add a background color in IE6-8 only and remove it with the Chroma filter**.

*Note: All the other types of box-shadow recipes that follow should also use this Chroma filter method when it is desirable to have a transparent background in the box itself.*

**Type 1b: Negative Shadow Offsets**

If there are negative shadow offsets, you will see a small difference with the position of the box being shadowed:

```
#box {
  /* CSS for all browsers. */
  border: solid 1px #808080;
  background: #ffffcc;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;

  /* CSS3 Box-shadow code: */
  box-shadow: -10px -5px 0px #ff0000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -10px -5px 0px #ff0000;
  -moz-box-shadow: -10px -5px 0px #ff0000;
}

/* IE6-8 Specific Code */
body.ie6 #box,
body.ie7 #box,
body.ie8 #box {
   zoom: 1;
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(OffX=-10, OffY=-5, Color=#ff0000);
}
```

**Type #2: Glowing box-shadow**

The second `box-shadow` I use a lot is what I call the “glowing box” effect. This happens when a shadow with a large blur radius is put directly behind a box (i.e. the x- and y-offsets are set to 0, and the blur-radius is a non-zero number). It is possible to simulate this effect in IE using the **Shadow filter**. This filter must be applied four times (north, south, east and west of the box) in order to simulate the `CSS3` effect. Here is the CSS recipe:

```
#box {
   box-shadow: 0 0 5px #666666;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #666666;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #666666;
}   

body.ie6 #box,
body.ie7 #box,
body.ie8 #box {
   zoom: 1;
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=5, Direction=0),
         progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=5, Direction=90),
         progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=5, Direction=180),
         progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=5, Direction=270);
}
```

**Two important caveats about the Visual Filter rules:**

As mentioned before, the `CSS` for IE6-8 uses a lighter color for the shadow. This is due to the way the Shadow filter behaves: it requires a lighter shade to simulate the same effect.
Also he Visual Filters examples are pushed down and to the right compared to the `CSS3` example. This is for the same reasons as stated in **Type 1b**, and a developer would again have to use margins or positioning to get the box in exactly the same place as it is in IE6-8.

Comment: Really usefull @bodi0, 

`border-collapse: collapse;`

was the problem ! thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to "cheat" by adding:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

This will tell IE to render using up-to-date standards, which includes the `box-shadow`.

However, this is at best a hack and probably won't help much. You should really focus on fixing the bug that's stopping you from properly declaring a `<!DOCTYPE>`.

Comment: This fix as the same effect that when I use `<!DOCTYPE html>`, the box shadow work fine, but the iframe login freeze. I can't fix this bug because the iframe url is generate by an other compagny.
Hope I can bypass this bug because if I must wait for an iframe Fix, It can be very very long...But thank for your help Niet.

Answer (score 0):

The `doctype` tag is not a replacement for the `html` tag, you should have both.

If you have only the `doctype` tag and not an `html` tag, the markup is invalid. The browser will try to make the best of the broken code, but there are a number of ways that it can misinterpret parts of the rest of the code.

If you have only the `html` tag and not a `doctype` tag, the browser will parse the page in quirks mode, which is basically using the oldest standards possible. This will disable some features from newer standards, like CSS3.

If you can't use the HTML5 doctype, you should use one for an older standard, for example HTML 4.01:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

W3C has a list of [Recommended Doctype Declarations](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) where you can see the different versions and variations.